# Issue with C code while making a parallel version of Odd-Even sorting

Tags: c, linux, gcc, while-loop, openmp

I was making a C code about odd-even parallel sorting using OpenMp. The code is the following:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int *A,N,i,sw=1,start=0,temp;

srand(0);

printf("Inserire la grandezza dell'array: ");
scanf("%d",&N);

A=(int *)calloc(N,sizeof(int));

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    A[i]=rand()%100+1;
    printf("%d  ",A[i]);
    }

while(sw || start){
    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=start;i<N-1;i+=2){
        if(A[i]<A[i+1]){
            temp=A[i];
            A[i]=A[i+1];
            A[i+1]=temp;
            sw=1;
        }
    }
    if(start==0) start=1;
    else start=0;
}

printf("\n\n");

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("%d  ",A[i]);
    }

return 0;

}
```

But when I run it it will "stop" before the scanf. I used stop because it goes into the while but doing it in loop without quitting it, and also it doesn't print anything if I place a printf after the scanf.
I'm using Linux compiler gcc (Debian 10.2.0-16) 10.2.0 on a Virtual Machine

Comment: `while(sw || start)` is an infinite loop because you never set `sw` to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't see it

Comment: Also, please, please, please, allocate your variables in their minimal scope. That has been in C since C99 (at least), and this is a new code, so there is no excuse for writing it in the way you have. Here, in particular, consider the scope of `temp`, and whether you *really* wanted only a single, shared copy...